# Extracting the coefficient

Tags: discrete-mathematics, generating-functions

So I have found the following through a series of differential equations and exponential generating functions: $[\displaystyle\frac{x^n}{n!}](\displaystyle\frac{1}{2}x^2 + x + 1)e^x$.

I got this in the following way:
$$A(x)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_n\frac{x^n}{n!}\ .$$
Then
$$\eqalign{A(x)
  &=1+\sum_{n=1}^\infty(a_{n-1}+n)\frac{x^n}{n!}\cr
  &=1+\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{x^n}{(n-1)!}
    +\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_n\frac{x^{n+1}}{(n+1)!}\cr
  &=1+xe^x+\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_n\frac{x^{n+1}}{(n+1)!}\ .\cr}$$
Differentiating both sides leads to the differential equation
$$\frac{dA}{dx}-A=(x+1)e^x\ ,$$
and solving with the initial condition $A(0)=1$ gives
$$A=(1+x+\tfrac12x^2)e^x\ .$$

My question is, how do I extract the coefficient of $\displaystyle\frac{x^n}{n!}$?

As much as a pain it might be, a detailed explanation would be greatly appreciated.  This is simply something I would like to thoroughly understand.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that $e^x$ itself represents a power series in $x$. So

$$(1 + x + \frac{1}{2}x^2)e^x = 1 \cdot \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \dfrac{x^n}{n!} + x \cdot \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \dfrac{x^n}{n!} + \frac{1}{2}x^2 \cdot \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \dfrac{x^n}{n!}$$

What's the coefficient of $x^n$ in this series? Well, it's the sum of the coefficients of $x^n$ in each of the three series. For example, the coefficient of $x^6$ will be $\dfrac{1}{6!} + \dfrac{1}{5!} + \dfrac{1}{2 \cdot 4!}$

Comment: Hmmm that does make much more sense thank you!  I have seen some stuff about the **Iverson bracket** floating around here on stackexchange regarding problems similar to this one.  Would you know if we could implement that in any way?